# How to query for date ignoring its time in ISODate value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I need to search for birthday ignoring the time in the date.

For example these documents

```
{
  "birthday" : ISODate("2016-03-02T23:00:00Z")
},
{
  "birthday" : ISODate("2016-03-02T13:00:00Z")
}
```

should be found for the parameter `2016-03-02`.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
const value = '2016-03-02'
Content.find({ 'birthday': new Date(Date.parse(value)) })
```

Comment: A "day" is the *range of possible milliseconds* from start to end.

Comment: @NeilLunn But how do I get the range element from the input string?

Comment: `new Date(value)`. Pretty sure that's what the linked duplicate shows you as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't see it in the answer. I'm using `Date.parse` to get the date, but with that I just get the first time of the range, not the second one.

Comment: You are using "equality" and not a **"range"**. Read the answer(s) ( there's quite a few ) They show you what `$gte` and `$lt` are.